# Logic, need help to find out what that abbreviations means

Tags: logic

My native language is Portuguese, so I'll translate the question.
Note that I haven't found relative content to that question on my language, but I found out that one of the abbreviations means Main Connective.
I know only some part of the others abbreviations.
Can you help me to find out what the others abbreviations means? They might be correlated.
[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: The first one is ill-formed, the $P\to \neg R\to Q$ bit doesn't make sense. And what is $w$? Do you have any idea of what the main connective is?

Comment: I know what main connective is, I mean, I need to know the abbreviations on the enunciation, like C.P means Main Connective, I don't know what is P.I, P.M and P.U, I know the symbols.

Comment: It might be a good idea to also post the question in portuguese below the english version. Someone can help you translate it.

Comment: I did, the portuguese question is also in the image, the problem is that there's only the abbreviations.

Comment: Well, where did you get this problem from? This should be explained on your notes, text or whatever.

Comment: Actually is a Word document, it's not related to any website, I just downloaded it from a non math related site.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you very much.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, if you answer this question I can set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that they are connected with the formation tree for propositional formulae.

See for example : R.Smullyan, *First-Order Logic* (1968), page 8:

> The notion of *immediate subformula* is given explicitly by the conditions:
>
> (i) Propositional variables have no immediate subformulas.
>
> (ii) $\lnot X$ has $X$ as an immediate subformula and no others.
>
> (iii) The formulas $X \lor Y, X \land Y, X \rightarrow Y$ have $X,Y$ as immediate subformulas and no others.
>
> We shall sometimes refer to $X,Y$ respectively as the left immediate subformula, right immediate subformula of $X \lor Y, X \land Y, X \rightarrow Y$.

The *main connective* is the first connective that "pops up" when you start from a "complex" formula $\alpha$ written with all the couples of parentheses and you start deleting the outermost couple; i.e.it is the connective labelling the root of the formation tree.

In $(P→(¬(Q→R)))$ is the leftmost $\rightarrow$. In $((P→(\lnot Q))→R)$ it is the rightmost.

*Please, check...*